# Esker ActiveX Plug-in for Firefox under Linux?

Tags: linux, firefox, activex

I have installed the windows version of Firefox with [winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks) under Fedora, hurrah!

I heard that there is an Esker ActiveX Plug-in for Firefox, but I can't find it. I need it for visiting a website that uses Active X and by default it's only working under IE6.. :D (but it works perfectly under windows if the Firefox has the IE TAB plug-in installed.)

Where is the offical Esker ActiveX Plug-in for Firefox?

It woud be a great help to have activex under Fedora... :\

Comment: IE6 only? Seriously? This sounds like a job for having a little windows virtual machine sitting around in VirtualBox that you can startup to access stupid IE6 only sites. Fighting wine, activex, libraries, and such is going to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: that is the solution that had been used for a long time. but we want to get rid of these vm's.

Comment: As far as manageability goes, using wine and activex on linux is going to be a step backwards: it will be harder to manage and more brittle than a working VM image you can distribute and maintain in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use [ies4linux](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page) if you need Internet Explorer and you are under a *NIX system.

As they said :

> IEs4Linux is the simpler way to have Microsoft Internet Explorer
>   running on Linux

It can even install IE5 on your desktop. IEs installed support some ActiveX, but not all of them. Their [known issues](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Known_issues) page says that :

> ActiveX may not work with some special cases